# recursive ajax or setInterval(), WHICH ONE IS BETTER?

Tags: ajax, recursion, settimeout, setinterval

I am trying to fetch the message table and append the response on the previous fetched results...

here are 2 approaches I have tried, **but all failed**

1st: recursive fetch

```
function fetch(){
        $.ajax({ 
               url: url,
               type: "post",
               data:data,
               timeout: 3000,
               success: function(data){
                      $(selector).append(data);
                      setTimeout(function(){fetch()},3000);
               }
        })
}
```

2nd: setInterval()

```
   setInterval(function(){fetch()},3000);
   function fetch(){
                $.ajax({ 
                       url: url,
                       type: "post",
                       data:data,
                       timeout: 3000,
                       success: function(data){
                              $(selector).append(data);
                       }
                 })
    }
```

after few successful ajax call, the browser went frozen and console shows **"net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE "** OR **"ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT"**

please advise

**thank you**

Comment: If your other fetch is to be called when your first one succeeds, why are you using setInterval?  Also, you can just write setInterval(fetch,3000), you don't have to wrap it in a function call.

Comment: they, recursive and setInterval, are not working after few successful call, so I am asking how to improve those code, thanks your time..

Answer (score 0):

You may this this if you want to make a recursive call after success or failure

```
function fetch(url, selector){
    $.ajax({ 
       url:url,
       type:"post",
       data:data,
       timeout:3000,
       success:function(data){
           $(selector).append(data);
           fetch();
       },
       error:function(data){
           fetch();
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: yes, or I can put it at complete:function(data){
           fetch();
       }...thank you, but the browser still went frozen after few calls

Comment: This is because of we are continuously adding html to page which cause the browser to be frozen after few calls...

Comment: understand...but I think the issue should be browser is waiting for returning data from server; however, server doesn't response (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)...do you have any idea how to improve it?